# Finding duplicate on java using generics

Tags: java

I am new to generics and I want to find the duplicate data using generics.So, I tried like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RemoveDuplicate {
    
    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] i= {12,12,12,12,5,2,42,4,2,5,3,35,3,1,23,54,44};
        removeDuplicates(i);
    }
    
    public static <T extends Number> T[] removeDuplicates(T[] list) {
        Map<T,Integer> duplicateCounr=new HashMap<T,Integer>();
        for(T t:list) {
            
           Integer x=duplicateCounr.get(t);
          
           if(x==null) {
               duplicateCounr.put(t,1); 
           }
           else {
               Integer count=duplicateCounr.get(t);
               duplicateCounr.put(t,++count); 
           }
        }
        List<? extends Number> nList=new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (Map.Entry<T, Integer> entry : duplicateCounr.entrySet()) {
            T key = entry.getKey();
            Integer v = entry.getValue();
            if(v>1) {
                nList.add(key);
                System.out.println("Duplicate" + key + ", Count: " + v);
            }
            
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I am getting error at `nList.add(key);`.Since,I will only pass either double,float,int values so I declared `List<? extends Number> nList=new ArrayList<>();`.Why this duplicate data are not being inserted in this `nList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add to this type of list because you don't know what type of object is going to be passed.

```
List<? extends Number> nList=new ArrayList<>();
```

instead you can use

```
List<T> nList=new ArrayList<>();
```